# How to store this JSON file in a Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have never worked with JSON files before. I have this News Classification dataset. I wanted to get this in a Pandas dataframe.
It looks like this:

```
{"content": "Unions representing workers at Turner   Newall say they are 'disappointed' after talks with stricken parent firm Federal Mogul.","annotation":{"notes":"","label":["Business"]},"extras":null,"metadata":{"first_done_at":1521027375000,"last_updated_at":1521027375000,"sec_taken":0,"last_updated_by":"nlYZXxNBQefF2u9VX52CdONFp0C3","status":"done","evaluation":"NONE"}}
{"content": "SPACE.com - TORONTO, Canada -- A second\\team of rocketeers competing for the  #36;10 million Ansari X Prize, a contest for\\privately funded suborbital space flight, has officially announced the first\\launch date for its manned rocket.","annotation":{"notes":"","label":["SciTech"]},"extras":null,"metadata":{"first_done_at":1521027375000,"last_updated_at":1521027375000,"sec_taken":0,"last_updated_by":"nlYZXxNBQefF2u9VX52CdONFp0C3","status":"done","evaluation":"NONE"}}
```

There are more entries but I have posted just two of them. Each entry is bracketed as {}. Each entry has 4 keys: 'contents', 'annotations', 'extras', 'metadata'. I would like to have this in dataframe with the above keys as columns.

I tried the json library and Pandas.read_json function but both gave me errors.

```
with open('News-Classification-DataSet.json') as data_file:
  df=json.load(data_file)
```

This gave an error: `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 378)`

Comment: This is my first time posting so please edit my question as you see fit.

Comment: your json file, is each entry on separate lines? Just looking at your sample data_file that you give, I notice it's missing a `,` between each set of brackets, meaning it isn't a valid json structure

Comment: like this ? `pd.read_json("News-Classification-DataSet.json", lines=True)`

Comment: @pythonjokeun Yes that worked!! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to read this file in for each line, as the way you have it, isn't a valid json format.

So to read that in:

```
import json

data = []
with open('News-Classification-DataSet.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Now you should be able to work with that, however, what do you want as your datframe output?

If you want to go straight to a dataframe, you can do as suggested:

```
df = pd.read_json("News-Classification-DataSet.json", lines=True)
```

But you have nested columns which I don't know how you want to deal with that.

Comment: You can use [pandas.io.json.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)(data) to flatten/unravel the nested json, resulting in a dataframe with one row per list element in data, one column per json attribute.

Comment: The second solution is what I needed. I can manipulate the data frame to get the things I need. Thanks!!

Comment: @chitown88 any particularly relevant limitations for this context? I haven't used that function much.

Comment: It usually has it limits when there are lots of nested lists and dictionaries. In this particular example, the only thing I see is the `data['annotation']['label']`. Those values under the `label` key are lists. Now granted they are only lists of 1 element, but they get strored in the dataframe as a list. So if there were multiple items in those lists, you'd need to find a way to flatten out that as well. It's not impossible, would just require some extra logic. But as long as the json is in a "nice"/simple structure and consistant, I've found `json_normalize` to work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

To load line delimited json into a dataframe,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("News-Classification-DataSet.json", lines=True)
```

To parse the `dict` inside columns into columns,

```
pd.concat(
    [
        df["annotation"].apply(pd.Series),
        df[["content", "extras"]],
        df["metadata"].apply(pd.Series),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```